# How to change icarousel radius according to the screen size?

Tags: ios, swift3, icarousel

Hello I want to make half circle rotating wheel. So I used `iCarousel` for this. My problem is how to change the radius of the wheel according to the screen size.

These are my constraints. 
[image]

This red view is the `iCarousel` view
[image]

Comment: Play around with storyboard demo of icarousel. Hope you will get the required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an values `iCarouselOptionRadius` . This value definesradius of the Rotary, Cylinder and Wheel transforms .The radius of the Rotary, Cylinder and Wheel transforms in pixels/points. This is usually calculated so that the number of visible items exactly fits into the specified arc. You can manipulate this value to increase or reduce the item spacing (and the radius of the circle).

I hope you equipped with all demos of iCarousel. Check the **Options Demo** for an example of the effect that **iCarouselOption values** parameters have. You can download complete demo from [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel).

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!

Comment: I am changing this,, but it doesnt work 100% do you know where I can change the center point of the circle?

Comment: I could not get any such property to manipulate center point of circle. Have a look at [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107687/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-spinning-wheel) Ray Wenderlich to understand the maths of spinning wheel better. Hope it helps.

Comment: You can even raise query on Github. His team can help you. He replies promptly. :)